# vba Word show multiple Tags in Msgbox

Tags: vba, ms-word, tags, runtime-error

I want to show multiple Tags using Messagebox.

1. I open new Word document and go to Backstage / Info and type in Properties
   Title: Wordtags
   Tags: Red;Blue;Green
2. I use **on purpose** semicolons and not commas because then in Explorer I can then use in the search box Tags:Red and it finds all red tagged documents.
3. The following code does work for display Title but gives error on display Tags:

```
    Sub MsgBox_Tags()
    
    Dim sTitle As String
    
    Dim sTags As String
    
    sTitle = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    
    MsgBox sTitle
    
    sTags = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Tags").Value
    
    MsgBox  sTags
    
    End Sub
```

MessageBox Title works but then
Run time error '5' invalid procedure call or argument

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it appears as "Tags" on the Backstage view this is actually the "Keywords" property. You can see this by displaying the Properties dialog - in Backstage view click on Properties and select Advanced Properties.

```
Sub MsgBox_Tags()
   Dim sTitle As String
   Dim sTags As String

   sTitle = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value
   MsgBox sTitle

   sTags = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value
   MsgBox sTags

End Sub
```